# Google App Script stops running after 20-30 seconds

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to run a countdown script, but it seem to stop every 20-30 seconds.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;
    if (range.getA1Notation() == 'C1' && range.getValue() == true) {
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getRange('Q1');
    var timeLeft = 120; // in seconds
     cell.setValue(timeLeft);
    for (var i = timeLeft; i >= 0; i--) {
      Utilities.sleep(1000); // pause execution for 1 second
      cell.setValue(cell.getValue() - 1 + '\n');
       SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     }
    
    cell.setValue('');
    }
    }
```

I have tried increasing and decreasing the 'sleep' time as well as adding spreadsheetapp.flush(), but neither have kept the script running.

I expect the function to count down by 1 every second

Comment: It looks like there is a limit of 30 seconds for custom function runtime, which should explain it.  Is there any way around that or any other creative ways to call sequential functions?

Comment: `sleep(1000)` - "Sleeps for specified number of milliseconds." [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds). So 1000 is a small fraction of a second. 1 minute would be 60000 milliseconds.